# How to create custom MvcView scaffold that considers EF's DatabaseGenerated attribute

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, natural-key, t4scaffolding

Yes, I have a project where I'm using my EF 6.x entities as if they were also my ViewModels - no AutoMap for me - I've studied and understand the risks.

My database has a lot of natural keys. In my Code First POCOs, I have properties that look like this:

```
Partial Public Class ProfilePriceGroup

    <Key> <DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)>
    Public Property ProfileId As Long

    Public Property TargetRegion As String

    Public Property Discount As Decimal = 0D

End Class
```

I'm experimenting with editing the scaffolding templates (my project features the 'CodeTemplates' directory via the SideWaffle VSIX), and I'm specifically trying to affect the razor generated by default for MvcView/Edit.vb.t4

Since the key is important information to reflect back to the model binder, the default scaffold renders a hidden input, but, in the case where it is DatabaseGeneratedOption.None - I wish it would render an additional visible label so users readly understand what 'ProfileId' they are editing.

In other words, the default scaffolding presumes surrogate keys which would be un-interesting in the view, but, my keys ARE interesting for my views.

I'm not interested in the <HiddenInput(DisplayValue:=True)> DataAnnotation that is part of the System.Web.Mvc namespace that acheives this. I do want to keep my EF project free of the MVC libraries for now.

I can see readily how the current MVC scaffolding iterates over types of PropertyMetadata from a passed-in ModelMetadata parameter that is a type of Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Core.Metadata.ModelMetadata

But, how do I cross over and get this DatabaseGenerated attribute, which I think derives from the System.Data.Metadata.Edm namespace?

Comment: I think I may have stumbled upon a solution using modelProperty.IsAutoGenerated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can see the resulting scaffolding snippet for my Edit.vb.t4 template:

```
@Using (Html.BeginForm())
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4><#= ConvertCamelCaseStr(ViewDataTypeShortName) #></h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<#
For Each modelProperty As PropertyMetadata in ModelMetadata.Properties
    If (modelProperty.Scaffold) AndAlso (Not modelProperty.IsAssociation) Then
    If (modelProperty.IsPrimaryKey) Then
            If (modelProperty.IsAutoGenerated) Then
#>
    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.<#= modelProperty.PropertyName #>)
<#
            Else
#>
        <!-- natural key - we will show the value and a hidden input -->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.<#= modelProperty.PropertyName #>, New With { .class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.<#= modelProperty.PropertyName #>)
                @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.<#= modelProperty.PropertyName #>)
            </div>
        </div>
<#
            End If
    ElseIf (Not modelProperty.IsReadOnly)
#>
```

The part that makes my scaffold work is the `If (modelProperty.IsAutoGenerated) Then` piece.. my special stuff is in the `Else` and is a departure from the OOTB T4 MVC 5/EntityFramework templates